# How can I get specific rows from the data frame rather than seeing if my conditions are simply true or false?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a data frame from a smaller data frame using this code:

```
seed_request = [(inventory.location == 'Brooklyn') & (inventory.product_type == 'seeds')]
print(seed_request)
```

This is giving me a new data frame with either True or False depending on if these conditions are met. How do I make it instead give me a data frame with the rows that satisfy these conditions?

Comment: `inventory.loc[(inventory.location == 'Brooklyn') & (inventory.product_type == 'seeds')]`

Comment: You may think about accepting an answer to reward those how helped you, or at least comment to explain what's missing ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the filter on the dataframe

```
seed_request = inventory[(inventory.location == 'Brooklyn') & (inventory.product_type == 'seeds')]
```

Answer (score 2):

seed_request = [(inventory.location == 'Brooklyn') & (inventory.product_type == 'seeds')]
print(inventory.iloc[seed_request])